# Get permissions on /var/www

Tags: permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

Ive installed a LAMP server in my machine, and I would like to edit the files in /var/www/ but I dont want to have to switch to super user everytime.

How can I set the permissions so that I can edit the contents of the folder with my everyday user account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo chown -R everydayUser:everyDayUserGroup /var/www

## Edit

Actually set the group to the group your browser is using so that it doesn't loose access to it.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: got it. "sudo usermod -a -G www-data myusername". Thanks.