# Trying to install phpmyadmin but can't move from one folder to /var/www

Tags: phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

I can't seem to move folders or create new folders in the /var/www folder. This is the first time i have tried using Ubuntu and i can't seem to find a reason why i'm not able to move folders, i only have one account so should have all the priviliges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the proper filesystem privileges:

```
sudo chown <youruser>:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod 0775 /var/www
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Replace `<youruser>` with your own username. No logout/login required.

Answer (score 0):

The /var/www/ folder is normally owned by root.

Try this

```
sudo chmod 0775 /var/www 
sudo chown root.www-data /var/www 
sudo usermod -a -G www-data your-username
```

logoff then login, then try writing back to the /var/www folder

Comment: Just tried that, didn't seem to make any difference. The main thing i am trying to do is set up localhost. Is there a way to give all root priviliges to my account ?

Comment: No this is not possible. You can only gain root privileges via sudo or su for a normal user account. Generally it is not a good idea working with root privileges all the time.