# What is the default permission for /var/www?

Tags: filesystem, permissions, www

After upgrading to 12.04, I had to reinstall the LAMP stack. Then I brought all my www project folders from a pen drive to the `/var/www` folder (using `sudo nautilus`, and dragging the files in there).

Now I cannot make any changes to the files/directories within `/var/www`.
Perhaps this changed with the backup copies I dragged in there.

I'd like to know what the *default* permissions for the `/var/www` folder are. I don't want to just change the permissions and make my system abnormal and working. Rather I'd like to get it to the correct state that is meant to work.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *default* permissions should be set to `drwxr-xr-x` with `root` being the owner and `root` is the default group of the directory

Now if you want to modify the files in that directory, then you will have to change permissions to make your username the owner

```
sudo chown -R username /var/www/
```

Personally, on my developing machine, I choose to create a `www` folder somewhere under my home folder and modify Apache's `DocumentRoot` to serve from that directory instead of `/var/www`.