# How can I rename a folder using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, directory, rename, www

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

I need to rename it in the terminal because it is in the root directory in Lubuntu.

- I have a folder in `/var/www/` which I need to change the name of from htdocs to xoops but I would not be able to do it by right clicking because I don't have permissions. This is why I want to do it in the terminal so I can do it as root.

Comment: Given your comment, this question seems specifically about how best to make changes to the contents of `/var/www`. An earlier question, [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www), covers this quite well. I recommend that you take a look there. Also, we should probably close this question as a duplicate of that one, so people who find this are prominently directed there.

Comment: I see your point but they are asking for the most simple way which is pretty subjective. Whereas I specifically wanted to know how to do it in the terminal.

Comment: Do you feel that the terminal-based answer to that question doesn't meet your needs? If so, can you explain why? Your question can be edited and reopened if it becomes clear it's really a different question requiring a different answer.

Comment: No the terminal based answer is perfect for my question, just not quite sure it is the best answer for the person who asked the other question, which seems much more broad. There is perhaps not a lot that can be done about that though.