# How to create files and directorys in var/www?

Tags: lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

I've just finished installing LAMP on Ubuntu and I've gone to start created a website directory and I don't know how to get into the "root" directory of LAMP.

Can I use the terminal? if so what would be the commands to create a new folder and create sub-folders inside that directory. Also save PHP, CSS files into the directory and also images.

Comment: ^Possible duplicate - it's not I looked at that before posting it didn't really tell me anything, just like I searched all over google...

Comment: It does explain how to open the file browser so you can put files in there. For using the terminal, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Comment: The question has been answered... Is this really needed to be discussed? Hell... we all need to evolve...

Comment: @Will If you believe this is not, in effect, the same question as [that older question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www), please explain why in a comment. It seems to cover the same ground, so we'll probably be closing this as a duplicate of that question. (But it can be reopened, if it turns out we're wrong.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a terminal use the next commands:

**cd** = [Change Directory](http://ss64.com/bash/cd.html)

```
cd /var/www
```

**mkdir** = [Make Directory](http://ss64.com/bash/mkdir.html), this command requires elevated privileges, so run it with sudo or gksudo

```
sudo mkdir foldername
```

(where foldername is the name of the folder that you wish to create).

You can create subfolders from within `/var/www` without changing to the desired destination by using:

```
sudo mkdir foldername/subfolder
```

**cp** = [Copy one or more files](http://ss64.com/bash/cp.html) to another destination

```
cp PATHTOSOURCE/file.php PATHTODESTINATION
```

This can be used for any kind of file.

Note: If you wish to use a GUI for these tasks, you can use Nautilus with elevated privileges, simply hit Alt+F2 and write `gksudo nautilus`, then Enter after which you will see Nautilus File Browser, press Control+L and write `/var/www` and you can copy/paste or drag/drop anything you wish with ease.

For a comprehensive list of the commands, visit: http://ss64.com/bash/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

By default files under /var/www are protected. To create content under /var/www you must have root privilege.

To gain root privilege use

```
sudo su
```

**Check Apache**

To make sure your apache is running fine open your browser and open http :// localhost/
 . If you get a message saying **"It works"** Your lamp installation is successful.

**Test php**
Using terminal create a test php file

```
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | sudo tee /var/www/test.php
```

restart apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Now open **http://localhost/test.php** in your browser. You should get the php related configurations as output.

**To create directory**

mkdir

eg: `mkdir my_website`

**To copy files**

cp source destination

eg: `cp /tmp/test.php /var/www/my_website/`

**To copy whole directory**

cp -r source_dir dest_dir

eg `cp -r /tmp/mywebsite_content /var/www/my_website`

Answer (score 0):

You could do so very easily by using **Nautilus**, the default graphical user interface file manager of Gnome which is powering Unity in Ubuntu.

If for your own reasons would like to use the command line, the commands you should use are:

```
mkdir <name> example: mkdir fokis
```

makes a new folder named **name** in the **current working directory**.

```
cd <path>/ example: cd fokis/
```

changes the working directory to **path**.

```
pwd
```

shows the **current working directory**.

```
cp <file> <path> example: cp image.jpg /var/www/
```

copies **file** to **path**.