# Folders and files permission problem

Tags: server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

I just installed Ubuntu server 12.04, now when I create any folder in www/ the default permission is creating problem and every time I have to give permission manually.

Please give me the command to run so that when I create any folder or file in the www directory I do not have to give permission and it run by default.

thanks in advance

Comment: What are the permissions that are created by default and how would you like them to be?

Comment: when I create a folder the permission is drwx--- and I want them to be 655 or drw-r-xr-x this goes for files as well

Comment: I tried following

sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www

but now I can not enter into the directory. I dont what is the reason but my problem is still not solved.

Noddy