# How do I set up local Joomla sites for web developing?

Tags: permissions, lamp, web-development, joomla

I plan to develop multiple websites using Joomla. I'm using Ubuntu **Desktop**, and only need to access the sites and configuration files locally, while logged in to my user account.

Previously I tried this using `tasksel` and set up a LAMP server with files in `/var/www`, but then encountered problems with developing more than one site, and also permissions issues when editing code like CSS files.

**How do I set up multiple Joomla sites, each in its own directory and database, for developing on a local desktop machine?** Do I even need directories  outside of `/home`?

Related questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www) (*simplest way to add & edit files in /var/www*) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www) (*avoid sudo when working in /var/www*). This might even be a duplicate of one of those, unless there is a simpler solution for web developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [Name-based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) support in Apache.

First, you need to modify your `/etc/hosts` file to add some names which resolve to your local loopback interface:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1       test1
127.0.1.1       test2
```

Then, in your home directory, you create a directory for your sites, say, `sites` and a sub-directory for each one:

```
  sites\
  - test1\
  -- apache_config
  -- www\
  - test2\
  -- apache_config
  -- www\
```

Each `apache_config` file would define configuration for each of your virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName test1
 DocumentRoot /home/username/sites/test1/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you symlink all the configs into `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

```
ln -s /home/username/sites/test1/www /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-test1
ln -s /home/username/sites/test2/www /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-test2
```

Restart Apache.

And that technically should be it - all your sites and their configs are in your home directory, editable by you.

I haven't tested the steps, so it's just a general outline, but that's where I would start. I would avoid placing my work files into `/var/www` (or using Apache's default virtual host in general), and also I would avoid modifying Apache's main config file (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`) or the default virtual host file (the one in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`).