# Easy installation of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

I am wordpress theme and website developer. back in windows i use WAMP server to access and develop themes in wordpress now in ubuntu the process is heavy. I mean i have to install apache, php, mysql and have to create databases using terminal (in windows i can do this by using wamp user interface and deploying is also very simple). so please help me to choose the best server for wordpress.

and finally are there any server like wamp in ubuntu?

i am using ubuntu 12.10 desktop 32bit version!

Comment: take a look at bitnami stack for wordpress, the native installer. http://bitnami.org/stack/wordpress. It's much more useful to learn how to install the packages in Ubuntu manually, though.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/205441/12864), with a few links to other similars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used bitnami open source server.
Installation:

1. Download bitnami with wordpress [from the Bitnami site](http://bitnami.org/stack/wordpress)
2. Before Installing:

   First, move the bintami.Run file to your Home folder. This is just precautionary. Second, Right-click on the file and select Properties. Under the Permissions tab, tick the checkbox near the bottom labelled Allow executing file as program. Click Apply Permissions. Then Close the Properties Window.
3. install the bitnami [following these instructions](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-wordpress-with-bitnami)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly the Linux equivalent of WAMP is LAMP (though its more accurate the other way :) ) Unlike in windows most server software in Linux doesn't have GUIs by default; this is true for LAMP. To install make sure you have `tasksel` installed. at a terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Once complete then run `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`.

This will create the folder `www` in `/var/`, so you should see it in `/var/www` this will be your web root. (For **14.04** and above, it would `/var/www/html`.)

You can now unzip wordpress into that folder. Once complete, in a web browser go to `localhost/wordpress` (In your URL using Firefox/Chrome for example type localhost/wordpress, this will lead you to your wordpress installer) and follow the instructions there. If you want a GUI for database management I've always used [`phpmyadmin`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/phpmyadmin/). To install it run:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

then in a browser go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` (As mentioned above, use the URL in your browser to go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`)

Note that if you're running this server remotely then replace `localhost` with the remote **IP** you can have access to.

Comment: +1 For the "other way around". Also updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you have a good look into juju - see [here](https://juju.ubuntu.com/). See also Jorge's blog at [this page](http://www.jorgecastro.org/2012/03/18/redeploying-omg-ubuntu-onto-the-cloud-with-juju/). This is so cool ....

```
juju deploy wordpress
juju deploy mysql
juju add-relation wordpress mysql
```