# Installing wordpress on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: localhost, wordpress

I am trying to install wordpress locally. I tried the instructions described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227251/easy-installation-of-wordpress/227264#227264). But when I point my browser to `http://localhost/wordpress` it turns to a 404 not found page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once check your `/var/www` permissions it should be:

```
www-data:www-data
www-data=user
www-data=group
```

and also:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or:

```
sudo restart apache2
```

Comment: It is not the case for permissions, if that then it will show "permission denied"

Comment: This problem is done for misplacing virtual host.

Comment: Detail in here- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts