# How to install Joomla in Ubuntu as localhost?

Tags: apache2, localhost, joomla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up local Joomla sites for web developing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205441/how-do-i-set-up-local-joomla-sites-for-web-developing)

I have installed the lamp-server but i stuck in one certain step..

For those who are not familiar with Joomla installation the last step when you install Joomla at a host is to remove the installation folder. Here in action: The link of the youtube video is skipped the the last step (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tp34WHP8HKs#t=08m42s)

Were it says remove installation folder if i click the button "Remove installation folder:" it says "error" and i guess this is because it doesn't have root previlages.

So i run `sudo nautilus` go to the folder var/www, and remove the folder installation.. So now when i try to access my localhost

> No configuration file found and no installation code available.
>   Exiting...

I am confused, it asked me to remove it and now that i removed it, it needs it..:?

Comment: where **what** says "remove installation folder" ? Please be verbose: what are you doing, why and what do you expect.

Comment: You are right, not everyone is familiar with Joomla. I added more information with a video skipped to the step that i have problem :)