# User is part of a group - except he's not?

Tags: permissions, users

I'm really confused about this. I need to give a user read/write access to /var/www and followed the instructions in that question : [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to "/var/www"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www). All commands were succesful, no error message.

However...

```
[solarbear@candyland ~]$ cd /var/www
[solarbear@candyland www]$ touch hello
touch: cannot touch `hello': Permission denied
```

Okay so perhaps I didn't add my user properly to the group, no biggie.

```
[solarbear@candyland var]$ sudo adduser solarbear www-data
The user `solarbear' is already a member of `www-data'.
```

Huh... so I'm part of the group... right?

```
[solarbear@candyland var]$ groups
solarbear adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

So I'm part of the group but it's not listed under the `groups` command? How can that be?

As for /var/www, it seems to belong to the right group :

```
[solarbear@candyland var]$ ls -l /var
...
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 15 12:11 www
```

So 1) why is the www-data group not listed under `groups` and 2) how can I get to write files in /var/www with using `sudo`?

Comment: Have you tried to log out and then log in again? Afaik group information needs a relog to be updated.

Comment: Huh... you're right. I wasn't aware that I needed to log out first. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment above:

> Have you tried to log out and then log in again? Afaik group information needs a relog to be updated. – soulsource Jun 15 at 16:47