# Permission denied while writing a file in var/www in spite of adding me to user group

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, webserver

I gave permissions to read and write files in `/var/www` to the working user(me) through the steps given in [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www). It works fine when I try to create/read file in the project directory.

Say I am working in  `/var/www/xyz`

I am able to read and write files in this folder through a `php` code. Now, I have created a folder inside folder `xyz`, say `abc`

```
/var/www/xyz/abc
```

In my `php` code when I read a file situated inside `abc`, it works fine, but it gives me `warning: permission denied` when I try to *create a file* in this folder.

The exact warning is

```
Warning: fopen(abc/a.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/xyz/code.php
```

I was asked to provide some output:

```
stat /var/www/dodge
  File var/www/dodge' 
  Size: 4096 Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 directory
Device: 700h/1792d Inode: 1445503 Links: 8
Access: (2775/drwxrwsr-x) Uid: ( 33/www-data) Gid: ( 33/www-data)
Access: 2013-07-16 16:29:21.434531583 +0530
Modify: 2013-07-16 14:07:46.482782580 +0530
Change: 2013-07-16 16:28:04.622533850 +0530
 Birth: -

stat /var/www/xyz/abc
  File: /var/www/dodge/codes' 
  Size: 4096 Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 directory 
Device: 700h/1792d Inode: 1446465 Links: 2 
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x) Uid: ( 1000/ wq) Gid: ( 1000/ wq) 
Access: 2013-07-16 15:16:15.554661170 +0530 
Modify: 2013-07-16 15:13:42.698665686 +0530 
Change: 2013-07-16 15:13:42.698665686 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Comment: What is the output of `stat /var/www/xyz /var/www/xyz/abc`?

Comment: I just found out that the directory `xyz` has socket(s) permission. But the directory `abc` only has directory(d) permission.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Include the `ls -l` output on the folder in question as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2):

For this situation you need to add the `set-group-ID` bit on the directory `/var/www/xyz` so newly created directories inside inherit group from parent.

```
chmod g+s /var/www/xyz
```

See `man 2 chmod`

> S_ISGID  (02000)  set-group-ID  (set  process  effective  group  ID on
>   execve(2); mandatory locking, as described in fcntl(2); take a new
>   file's group from parent directory, as described in chown(2) and
>   mkdir(2))

See comments to the answer from referred post.

**Edit after comment:**

If you added the `setgid` bit on the parent directory *after* the subdirectory was created:

```
  File var/www/dodge' 
  Size: 4096 Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 directory
Device: 700h/1792d Inode: 1445503 Links: 8
Access: (2775/drwxrwsr-x) Uid: ( 33/www-data) Gid: ( 33/www-data)
Access: 2013-07-16 16:29:21.434531583 +0530
Modify: 2013-07-16 14:07:46.482782580 +0530
Change: 2013-07-16 16:28:04.622533850 +0530 <---added setgid
```

but the subdirectory was created before that:

```
  File: /var/www/dodge/codes' 
  Size: 4096 Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 directory 
Device: 700h/1792d Inode: 1446465 Links: 2 
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x) Uid: ( 1000/ wq) Gid: ( 1000/ wq) 
Access: 2013-07-16 15:16:15.554661170 +0530 
Modify: 2013-07-16 15:13:42.698665686 +0530 
Change: 2013-07-16 15:13:42.698665686 +0530 <---before ctime above
```

the `setgid` bit works when you create new files and directories. It will not work for any that have already been already created. So the `codes` directory is still owned by `wq` and group `wq` and the other user has no permission to create files there; that is why you get the same error as before. Either `chown` the subdirectory to set the correct group, or delete and recreate it.

```
chown :group /var/www/dodge/code
```

Comment: Its not working. Still the same warning `permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by adding the folder `xyz` to the group `var-www`. Thus, now I am able to write to the files in the sub-folders too