# Write permissions in /var/www folder

Tags: permissions, xubuntu

I followed the steps from https://askubuntu.com/a/51337/115811 to add my user to a www-data group and set the `/var/www/` dir group writeable.

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

This is `/var/www/` contents:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 25 08:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Oct 17 08:47 ../
-rwxrwsr-x  1 www-data www-data  177 Oct 17 23:51 index.html*
```

However when I try to `git clone` or `mkdir` in `/var/www/`, I am still getting "Permission denied". What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the output of the command `groups` with your user <username>, that should have access?

Comment: this line `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` made the directory to user `www-data` so other user can't write, why not try something like `chown -R :www-data /var/www`

Comment: @nickanor Perhaps you could add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` made the directory to user www-data so other user can't write, why not try something like `chown -R :www-data /var/www`

Answer (score -2):

`sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/`

I think the above will solve your problem `chmod 755` did not solve my problem.

Comment: be careful when you use 777 permission. Your folders or files will be accessed by everyone. For security reason this is not recommended.