# How do I save an uploaded file in PHP?

Tags: apache2, php

In PHP, I'm trying to save a file to the `/var/www/upload` directory, but whatever I try, it doesn't work.

I've tried giving `www-data` ownership of `/var/www` and subdirectories. I've tried modifying the code, to no avail. (Running Ubuntu Server 13.10)

Here's my code: (I'm trying to upload a png file.)

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      $hey = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      echo "\n" . $hey;
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you please tell us what error message you get? "I doesn't work" isn't enough to work with. What do you do and what happens then? What result do you expect? Please [edit your](http://askubuntu.com/posts/390842/edit) question and add the information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to "/var/www"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)