# Give user write access to folder

Tags: server, users, privileges

How do i give the user `'testuser'` write privileges on the folder: `/var/www/test/public_html`

Comment: I already saw that but I disagree that its a duplicate. My question  is very specific

Comment: If you have ACLs enabled: `sudo setfacl -Rm u:testuser:rwx /var/www/test/public_html`

Answer (score 253, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `chown`:

```
sudo chown -R testuser:testuser /var/www/test/public_html
```

This will make the user & group `testuser` the owner of the file. **IF YOU ARE USING A DIFFERENT USERNAME** *(run `whoami` or look before the `@` of your terminal promp, or be lazy and replace `testuser` with `$USER`)*, use that username instead. For instance user `Flora colossus` may have the username `groot`, in which case you would run `sudo chown -R groot:groot`... . If in doubt use the manual pages linked below.

or to use `chmod` (read and use **carefully**):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/test/public_html
```

Which will allow read-write-execute permissions for the owner, group, and **any other users**. The execute bit is required for directories to work, files can get by with `666` permissions (strictly speaking *most* files shouldnt need the execute permission, but this is least likely to break stuff and does not require `find` etc). `chmod` is much more difficult to 'undo' if needed that the other options.

Here are manual pages on [`chown`](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html) and [`chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) (these can also be found by running `man chown` and `man chmod`.)

I should add you can give groups of users write access as well (examples  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116073/52956) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/51337/178596)).

Also beware giving global write access with the `chmod` command if you have not as trustworthy users/scripts running on the server etc - I recommend changing the group or the user permissions instead. If using `chmod` please read up on this and understand what it is doing.

Comment: How does one undo chown?

Comment: @KarlMorrison For which of the above commands (with the same options), or a different one?

Comment: Was thinking about the `sudo chown -R testuser:testuser /var/www/test/public_html`!

Comment: Probably `sudo chown -R root:root /var/www/test/public_html`... what problems are you having?

Comment: Just curious! :) Never saw how to revert it before.

Comment: @KarlMorrison just for reference that doesn't necessarily 'revert' the change; it just assigns the owner to be root. If the owner were a different user you'd replace `root:root:` with the user's name and group

Comment: rubbish answer, applied to the theme folder & now its locked, not accessible.

Comment: @Kayote - change `testuser` to your username (and group)! Sorry forgot to add that :) I recommend reading the manuals on commands before running random commands off the internet, as there are often some caveats (and rarely, also malicous or just plain bad - e.g. this wouldn't be good in a setting where the web server files need to be owned by a particular user and group to work properly)

Comment: @Wilf yes, I was aware of that. Thankfully upon posting a question http://askubuntu.com/questions/838664/16-04-how-to-grant-read-write-access-to-folder-file-after-messing-up/838671?noredirect=1#comment1282607_838671 , I got the help needed to fix the system. :) Thansk for getting back.

Comment: Just change the user.. leave the group to www-data