# Do Not Have Permission to a Internal HardDrive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

So, I had an admin account on my computer. I created another one from it named `Rahul Holani`, and I later changed it to `RahulHolani`. I deleted the previous user and began working on the new one. Later I realized I cannot access a hard drive named `382 GB Volume` and another one named `10 GB Volume`. I have tried many commands including
`sudo chown -R 777 /382 GB Volume`, `sudo chown -R 777 /382-GB-Volume` and `sudo chown -R 777 -382GBVolume` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You almost have the right idea with chown/chmod.... you need to use chmod for those commands (with `-R -777 /path/to/folder`), and "382-GB-Volume" is not the path to the drive's folders. For a similar question I posted examples [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/402990/178596) (Read the manuals linked at the end). You need to enter the path to folder which you want permission to access

Comment: @Reg please don't add unnecessary formatting.

Comment: Sir,I understand by your reputation that you know a lot about ubuntu but @Reggie helped me a lot and my disk didnt get format. Maybe you read wrong or something. By the Way, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it sounds like you aren't using the correct path to your drive. You need to find the mountpoint of your drive, and change the permissions of that folder.

To find the mountpoint, open a terminal and type `mount`. This will show you a list of all the partitions mounted, and where they are mounted. Find your device and remember where it's mounted. If you don't know the device name, it will usually be mounted someplace in /media. Then use `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/your_mountpoint`, and it should work.

Comment: needs to be [`chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) not [`chown`](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html)....

Comment: Yep! I'll fix that in a sec.

Comment: I do not understand what the terminal is saying. Could you please help me find it? Below is what the terminal said

Comment: rahulholani@genesis10-desktop:~$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)

Comment: devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)

Comment: none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1001/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=rahulholani)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/rahulholani/96B9-4DB9 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1001,gid=1001,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda7 on /media/rahulholani/69beb9b4-a776-4536-9be4-f

Comment: aa52d9219b5 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
none on /tmp/guest-UEH4Kt type tmpfs (rw,mode=700)
/dev/sda6 on /media/rahulholani/45f1a81c-efca-4de6-8533-09875228b67c type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: @Rahul I think your drive is located at one of the folders in /media/rahulholani. I am going to guess that one is your 382GB Volume, one is your 10GB Volume, and there are 2 others. Figure out which one is the drive you want, and then replace `/media/your_mountpoint` with the path to the drive mountpoint you want. For example, `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/rahulholani/45f1a81c-efca-4de6-8533-09875228b67c` if that is the correct drive.

Comment: I didnt read your comment, I just copy pasted all of them.. And it worked! Thanks for the help Reggie, really appreciate it