# 16.04 - How To Grant Read Write Access To Folder / File after Messing Up

Tags: 16.04, permissions, filesystem, themes, directory

Folder : `/usr/share/themes`

I was trying to beautify my desktop so downloaded some themes. Found out that I don't have permission to paste the theme files to the above folder. So I used the guide here: [Give user write access to folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402980/give-user-write-access-to-folder)

This has messed up the system theme & now the folder is inaccessible and the system has a white theme (which I presume means no theme). Running `stat themes` gives :

```
xx@TPX260:/usr/share$ stat themes
  File: 'themes'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 2228383     Links: 17
Access: (0666/drw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-10-18 09:38:10.786996316 +0100
Modify: 2016-10-18 09:33:18.320935727 +0100
Change: 2016-10-18 09:35:18.308242550 +0100
 Birth: -
```

How can I get permissions of the directory back to the OS default so that themes can start working again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not read/write permission causing your problem - directories need `x` permission to be accessed. That one should have mode `755`, not `666`

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/themes
```

Check it looks like this:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/share/themes
drwxr-xr-x 43 root root 4096 Apr 20 23:13 /usr/share/themes
```

Check the permissions on the theme directories inside - they need to have `755` permissions as well

When you really need to add something to a system (root owned) directory, **don't touch the file permissions at all** - just use `sudo` to get elevated permissions for one command, for example:

```
sudo cp my_file /path/to/system/directory
```

Comment: Thankyou @Zanna. While the folder access has become `0755/drwxr-xr-x`, however,  the system is still not able to pickup the theme files & they are appearing in 'dark-green' color.

Comment: Just noticed, the individual theme files within the folder still have permissions of `0666/drw-rw-rw-`...

Comment: @Kayote ah I see you need to chmod 755 all the theme directories too