# Can't get index.html to open after lamp install on Ubuntu 14 on Amazon aws server

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

I can't believe I am struggling with this. I've set up ites on Centos but Apache on Ubuntu is so different. Running Ubuntu 14 on AWS. I want to setup joomla but I can't even get the default index.html that is included with apache2 to open! I am only going to have one website on this server. I installed all LAMP components via sudo apt-get install lamp-server^. Can someone tell me what if anything I need to do with apache2.conf, the file in sites-available and or the config file in sites-enabled?

I would have though that after the initial install of LAMP if I just entered the public address of my EC2 instance/index.html the default page would come up, but instead I get nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. I need to at least get the default index.html loading before I bother installing joomla.

I assume its something really simple that I am missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe of some help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `lamp-server` package installed correctly, everything should "Just work" and you should see the default Debian/Ubuntu apache page. On Ubuntu 14.04, the default `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/html`. The file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default` is the default virtualhost controlling that. (It's sym-linked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default` - any file in the `sites-enabled` directory is the actual virtualhost that's created).

(I'm not sure if the `lamp-server` package does any extra/odd configuration form installing all those packages manually - [read here to see the packages it installs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)).

Are your firewalls open to accept traffic from port 80? (This is usually related to AWS's security settings when you start up a server).

Lastly, I'll mention that I've gotten into the habit of installing the usual packages instead of the "catch all" `lamp-server` package. [Here's an example of that on 12.04](http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-12-04-lamp-server-setup) (the same commands will work for 14.04). If you want to see examples of various installs in Ubuntu 14.04, check out my [Vaprobash project](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash), which has a ton of bash scripts you can copy/paste from to run commands for installing LAMP/LEMP stacks. (Warning: It uses php5-fpm over apache's usual libapache2-php5 package. If you're unsure what that means, follow the first link above I have instead of the Vaprobash project).