# I get an Error When I start browser for execute php program in linux

Tags: xampp

1. I install Xampp Successfully in my ubuntu
2. I start xampp
3. Problem : When I open Localhost in my browser at time i get one Error as shown in picture:

[image]

Comment: This is the 1st time ever I see an "it works" interpretted as "one error". Nothing wrong here. All is as it should be.

Comment: Read it - it says 'It works!' :). Now you need to add your own content - there are various questions here that can help with getting 'permission' to do that  - e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www , http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. That's the regular message that you receive when you first install apache.

To start building your php application, edit your html files, they should be on /var/www/htdocs

Comment: I don't sloved that error if you know how that error sloved please know me using some steps or some details about that error