# How do I take root permissions?

Tags: permissions, root

I've just installed Ubuntu for the first time, and trying to set parameters for web server.
As I've understand I have to place my website inside /var/www/html folder, but I can't even create a file in there. What's the catch? How do I get root permissions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`gksu nautilus /var/www/html` in terminal

Comment: gksu is depreciaged and most servers are not running X

Comment: Don't know but it worked for me. I had to let it install 'gksu' program, and later it prompted me to create 'root/.config/nautilus folder' and now I'm looking at my webpage. Thank you very much Ike.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not a proper way to do this.

You should read: [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to "/var/www"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www) and follow the suggestions there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Terminal or SSH, instead of using your graphical interface, you just need prefix your commands with sudo.
Eg:

New folder:

```
sudo mkdir testsite
```

Edit a file:

```
sudo nano index.html
```

Also, a quick and dirty way of always giving yourself access:

```
sudo chown -R username /var/www/html
```