# Ubuntu 14.04 deleted www directory from /var/www and need to restore it

Tags: 14.04, permissions

I am new to Ubuntu as of yesterday and trying to upload a new site. When I was attempting to delete everything from `/var/www` I accidentally deleted the `www` directory as well. What steps do I need to take to rebuild/recover the directory with all of the appropriate permissions?

Comment: So you want to restore the directory even if it's empty, rather than wanting to recover the files? "recreate a directory" vs "recover deleted files" are quite different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the recommended permissions from https://askubuntu.com/a/51337/175814, as super-user run:

```
mkdir -m 0775 /var/www
chown www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: Aren't we supposed to have stuff in /var/www/html now?

Comment: I don't understand, how this would affect the issue at hand. (I'm hearing that for the first time.)

Comment: Well, if he wants to reproduce the original layout, I think it should include /var/www/html. Not a big deal by any means, I just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet tried reinstalling Apache, try that. You can do so by running:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2
```