# Sublime Text 3 authentication question when saving document

Tags: permissions

I am using Sublime Text for web developement. Every time I try to save changes (Ctrl+S), the authentication window pops up:

**Authentication is needed to run '/bin/cp' as the super user**

Obviously, when I enter the password, Sublime saves changes correctly. But when I press **Cancel**, another window pops up with an error:

**Error: administrator_copy_file (/tmp/.Some_File_Here, /var/www/Rest_Of_Path_Here) failed: Authorization failed**

As I am quite new to Ubuntu I don't know how to get rid of that authorization pop up.
I have all permissions to **/var/www** folder.

Comment: You're sure your user has write permissions to `/var/www` without becoming root (e.g. using `sudo`)?

Comment: @DavidBailey I have write permissions to `/var/www` but not to the subfolders. I've done `chown` on `/var/www` but when I've checked permissions on subfolders, ex. `/var/www/First_Site`, it belongs to `www-data`. I thought that `chown` on a main folder will give me permissions also to all subfolders/files in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have permission to write to `/var/www/Rest_Of_Path_Here`. ST3 is trying to elevate its UID to write as the correct user (hence the sudo prompt). I didn't know it could do this but I've tested it and it works so there you go.

There are a few ways you can fix this:

1. [Allow your user to write the files directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www). So many options here:

   - `chown` the files so you own them. This may upset things running as other users that might also need to write, eg a webserver running as www-user. You may need to change what they run as too.
   - Add your user to the `www-data` group  and change the file mask to `774` so members of the group can write/execute.
   - Change the file mask so *other* users can write (eg 777)... But this is pretty risky if there's something malicious on the server already.
   - Use [ACLs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) to allow your user to write without disturbing the standard permissions framework.
2. Change your workflow to write into a version control system (eg git) as your users, and then have a script running as the other user check it out. This carries other benefits.
3. Run ST3 as a user who can write there:

   ```
   sudo -u www-data subl /var/www/Rest_Of_Path_Here
   ```

   This is quite a lot uglier than just fixing the files.

Comment: You are right. I have only rights to **/var/www** folder, but not to all subfolders in it, which belongs to `www-data`. I think the best solution  here will be to add my user to `www-data` group.

Comment: Just to let anyone know. Adding my user to `www-data` group solved the problem. I just had to reboot the system after this. Thank you @Oli.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it by providing user right to the particular folder which I had to edit in Sublime text 3. I used the following commands:

```
sudo chmod 775 -R projectname/   
sudo chown username -R projectname/
```

I think it might be helpful to others in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot : )

Comment: Thank you. The chmod command worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your user to administrator user group by one of the below based on the version of Ubuntu you're using. Try both:

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin username
```

OR

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo username
```

If you're already in the admin group try a `chown` on the folder.

Comment: Why? There's every suggestion that they're already in the sudo/admin group (it works when they put their password in).

Comment: Maybe a `chown` will do @Oli

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, trying to edit my apache server's file with sublime-text and I don't want to mess up my webserver's permission. Changing your files g+w and putting your user in www-data group is not a very safe idea.

What I would advise is using SFTP plugin for sublime-text:

- duplicate your webserver's file to a folder belonging to your own user
- configure SFTP plugin with:

> ```
> "upload_on_save": true,
> "host": "localhost",
> "user": "www-data",
> ```

Do not provide a password in the configuration for this is a major security hole too.

Sublime-text will ask you for the password once and then will remember it for the session. Upon each file save, it will open an sftp session to localhost and will write the file to disk with the appropriate user

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following in your Linux/Unix terminal:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 project-name
sudo chown user-name project-name
```

Tried `-R 775` and didnt work so `-R 777` did the trick although I have given write permissions to all project

Answer (score 0):

Add your current user to `www-data` group.

`$USER` already has the current user  or you can change it for another user.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
```

Change permissions.

```
cd /var/www/Your_Project
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution would be to add your user to the www-data group with root user (sudo command):

```
usermod -a -G www-data your_username
```

Check if it is there:

```
grep ^www-data /etc/group
```

And do not forget to restart your system