# How to change file permissions and then revert them back

Tags: server, permissions, root, lamp, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website on my Ubuntu Server, and in order to change the theme, I need to set the file permissions. As I have read, it is unwise to permanently set the permissions to write for everyone, so I will have to enable them for the time I have to edit, and then revert them.

The problem is, I don't want to have to manually write down every permission on every file, and I am looking for a way to just revert them to earlier state.

Right now if I do this

```
ls -l /path/to/file.this
```

I get this

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26403 May 19 ......
```

So here's what I need:

1) If possible (**AND SAFE**), can I grant all the needed permissions to all files inside the `/html` folder to the Lamp Server, so I won't have to change them every time I need to edit the design of my website?

2) If not possible, how do I set the permissions I need in order to edit the file in Wordpress, and then change them back?

EDIT: Ok, I have done this

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html
```

Now I can edit the files from my Wordpress dashboard. Is this ok for security? Will the files be accessible only by me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to "/var/www"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

Answer (score 3):

1. files should be "644", directories should be "755". What you want is not permissions but you want to set the files and directories to a user and group that is allowed to write files into `/var/www/html/`.

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/*
   ```

   would set all to your current user or if you need something like "www-data" (the default apache user) change it to that. Wordpress has its own user, if you include that user to your group or the "www-data" group it can write files.
2. so this is not needed.

Comment: Why are you suggesting the OP change the ownership of a system dir? What's wrong with i) `sudo` or ii) adding themselves to the www-data group? In any case, this won't help since, presumably, the files they need to edit are in `/var/www/html/foo`.

Comment: what should be put in place of USER? Can I just give Lamp Server/Apache all the permissions inside '/www/html/' so I can edit them from my Wordpress dashboard whenever I want to?

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer I used $USER not USER, that uses your current user; you can also use "www-data" as user/group (is the default apache user) or if Wordpress has one and that is all you use, the wordpress user.

Comment: so I should use 'www-data' on both $USER in your example?

Comment: Yes you can. Set it to whatever you want but if you pick something non-default (www-data is default) you also need to edit apache conf.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just become root?

```
sudo -i
```

By switching the current user of your shell to root you can edit your files as the owner, which has the `w` flag set, without having any need to set any permission.

Once done, just run

```
exit
```

to switch back to the previous user

Comment: I don't want to edit them manually from the terminal, but from the Wordpress dashboard