# How to run php files in ubuntu?

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql

I installed apache2, php5 and mysql. `http://localhost/` url in browser shows it works. I saved a php file in `/var/www/` as testphp.php. Code in the file is..

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now on entering `http://localhost/testphp.php` in browser, it gives this error..

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening. Can anyone explain how to work with php? Also please explain how to connect php with mysql server installed on my system.

EDIT : I open the file from terminal in gedit. When I edit some text in the file, these warnings appear in the terminal..

```
(gedit:28157): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

EDIT2 : I saved the file to `/var/www/html` but still get the error.

Comment: Just save it in `/var/www/html`

Comment: @Parto I still get the same error on saving in `/var/www/html`

Comment: Check permissions -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www

Comment: How did you install Apache2 and PHP?

Comment: @muru `sudo apt-get install apache2` and `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php`

Comment: @Parto Thank You. It works now after changing the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The path where php file should be stored should be correct.
Store your php file of `/var/www/html/yourdirectory/filename.php`
follow above path and then in the browser type:

```
http://localhost/yourdirectory/filename.php
```