# Can't create folder or document in <var/www/html>

Tags: php, 16.04, html, www

how to enable to create New document or new folder in var/www/html ? "my Ubuntu is 16.04"

Comment: Do you have the permissions needed to create the file?  Please provide more information as to what you are trying to do and how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to "/var/www"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html
```

Comment: the only issue I see with this answer would be that /var/www should be owned by www-data:www-data. Wouldn't it have been more compatible to add the user to the www-data group?

Comment: You should avoid changing the system-wide files and directories to specific users.  You should either use the elevated (`sudo`) command to editing the create the needed files or add the username to the group of the owner.  You can also (as the second answer specifies), create a subfolder and make it owned by the user or group you intend to read/write  access to it.

Comment: @L.D.James;@JohnOrion.. I'm newer in ubuntu and i didn't know what to do but @magneto10's answer helped me:)

Comment: This post is actually a workaround and the disclaimers of what this would cause (as pointed out by @L.D.James) should be **clearly stated** in the post.

Comment: After try this sudo chown -R $USER:$USER usr in centos 7 , user login issue, before the command user login working. @Magneto10

Answer (score 3):

To do it from the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME
```

You don't want to give yourself ownership of /var/www/html

Comment: "You don't want to give yourself ownership of /var/www/html" good point but the "why?" should also be explained.