# Still not able to drag and drop files in my web file /var/www

Tags: permissions, web-development

I already tried [Azendale's answer to *Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?* question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www), unsuccessfully...

I want to work with Symfony and downloaded symfony.phar. The file is now in my /Download and I want to add it to my /var/www/html folder. Yet, it seems not to be possible... as when I drag  from the one side and drop it on the other side, it just come back to the first side. **Therefore, how to drag and drop files in my web file /var/www ?**

I thought it maybe was because I downloaded lampp and let it run evrytime I starrt my computer ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `/var/www` is writeable, for the user you have opened your X session with.

Alternatively, open a terminal, try to copy your data using `cp -rp ~/Downloads/xx /var/www`. Maybe you'll have some error message showing.

To ensure your user may write to `/var/www`, use:

```
sudo chown myuser /var/www
```