# How do I set up an FTP user with access to web root using vsftpd?

Tags: server, apache2, ftp, vsftpd

How do I set up an FTP user with access to web root using vsftpd?

I am currently setting up a website and I am trying to learn more about web servers on the way. I used shared hosting providers before, but this time I'd like to set up the server from scratch with a VPS. I installed a LAMP stack already and installed Wordpress. Everything works so far except for updating Wordpress automatically since it is asking for FTP access.

Therefore I installed `vsftpd` by following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-18-04). This also works accordingly.

The problem is that in the tutorial the FTP user has it's dedicated files directory (`/home/ftp_user/ftp/files`), but I need to give the user access to the web root (`/var/www/html/site`) for Wordpress performing the update.

I tried having the `local_root` point to `/var/www/html`

and I tried setting up a symlink like this

```
ln -s /var/www/html /home/ftp_user/ftp/files
```

but both ways do not work. When I try to connect, it says

```
vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

What is the proper way to achieve this? Or would it be better to not use the `/var/www/html` location at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP does not follow symlinks for good reasons. Instead, you should use a bind-mount.

```bsh
# Create mount directory below ftp/files
mkdir /home/ftp_user/ftp/files/www

# Mount
mount -o bind /var/www/html /home/ftp_user/ftp/files/www
```

Try if it works.

To make it permanent add this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/var/www/html /home/ftp_user/ftp/files/www none defaults,bind 0 0
```

Be aware that unlike a symlink, if you delete the `www`-folder you will remove all the files in `/var/www/html` too.

Comment: This solved one of my problems, but I still get the `vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()` error. However I could resolve that one by adding `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` to the `vsftpd.conf` file. I am not sure if it is secure to add that setting, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

The method described by [RoVo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/rovo) works for me. But I think I had 2 issues at the beginning (chroot and the symlinks).

By adding `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` to the `vsftpd.conf` file, it now also works to point the `local_root` to `/var/www/html`

I am not sure if it is secure to add the `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` setting, but it was mentioned on multiple sites/blog posts, e.g.

- [Ben Scobie: Fixing 500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot ()](https://www.benscobie.com/fixing-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot/)
- [Mattias Geniar: vsftpd on linux: 500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()](https://ma.ttias.be/vsftpd-linux-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-run-writable-root-inside-chroot/) .

To make the `local_root` work, I added this line to `/ect/vsftpd.conf`:

```
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-user-conf
```

and created a file with the name of the FTP user in the folder `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-user-conf/` with this content:

```
local_root=/var/www/html
```